# How do I find the secret, invisible house?

Tags: we-happy-few

In the quest "Johnny Bolton, Secret Agent!" the loon in the tree house, after running a couple of errands for him, asks me to fetch Empherial Linen from the Mystery House, as the quest log calls it, or the "secret invisible house", as he calls it.

He says that I can only see the house "at night and when you're very, very happy" and that "it's somewhere around here".
So, I'm assuming I have to be high on Joy at night. But after two useless runs of burning through all my Joy, running around like a lunatic, I've yet to find the house.

How do I find the secret, invisible house and how do I recognize it?

Comment: If I told you, it wouldn't be a secret anymore :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First all, if you are looking nearby, you are looking in the wrong spot, it is actually in the garden district which is across a bridge. The house isn't actually invisible either (at least at night it isn't), it looks like this.
[image]

Once you find it, pop a joy pill and you will be able to enter the gate and go into the house and find the linen.

Comment: "Around here" my shiny, glistening, dripping with drool Joy-pill! That's the last time I trust a word of a grown man hiding in a tree house. Anyways, I'm having a bit of trouble getting this far in the game, but I'll be sure to mark this accepted once I get there. Also, the markings next to the gate seem rather... subtle of a hint...

Comment: Sorry it took so long to mark this one answered. Kind of stopped playing the game and didn't start again untill recently. But, did manage to confirm this answer today.

Comment: N.B. in the current version you need a histoplamsa, not a Joy.

Comment: If I remember, I'll try to get an updated screenshot too.